# ClickOnce publish after each build

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, command, clickonce

This is the first time I want to deploy an application.

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution with two main projects : an ASP.NET MVC website and a WPF application.

In the end, I would like to have my entire solution into a deployment zip that I can import in IIS, and download my WPF application navigating to my publish.htm page (published with ClickOnce)... How can I do it ?

What I'm trying to do now :

I would like to publish the WPF application using ClickOnce into a folder of my website, and then create a deployment package zip for my website. Everything using MSBuild in command line...

I managed to create the zip for my website (in TeamCity), but I'm struggling with the ClickOnce part...

Questions :

1) Is this the way to do what I need ?

2) What do I have to put into "Publishing Folder Location" and "Installation Folder Url" in the Publish Tab of my project to publish into a folder of my website in my solution ?

3) How can I automatically publish my application after each build ? (use MsBuild in the post-build event ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)yes

2) since your using msbuild.exe at the command line, you'll be using the parameters there.
install URL:
/p:InstallURL=url/yourapp.application
outputpath:
outputpath=directory you want to publish to

3) I've used .cmd files that get called in the post-build event. That way if you have other tasks you want to do in the build you can. Like moving the build files to a .zip file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using TeamCity for continuous integration  and I finally managed to add MSBuild "build steps" to first deploy the application in a folder and then create the zip. I still don't know how to add my "ClickOnce installer" folder to the web deploy Zip file.   But I will look for it and create another question if necessary...